# Get Movie Data without imdb

Tags: c#, imdb

Im doing an small program(using C#) where i can get movie details. My first choice was to use imdb. But apparently imdb has change their website, so that all the  Web Scraping examples ore api i have found dosent work anymore. So my question is: Are there an alternative movie database that i can use instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Movie DB](http://www.themoviedb.org/) is opensource and has an [api](http://api.themoviedb.org) you can use.